# Json parsererror in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm currently working on a dropdown and having a lot of trouble. Its a dependent dropdown and so far I can get the correct data when I make a selection on the first dropdown but I cannot display it on the second dropdown. I know I get the data because I see it while debugging on chrome. This is an Example of what i get:

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"Hardware":1,"Software":2,"Other":3,"option":10}Page generated in 0.2831 seconds.<br><br><br>", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
parsererror
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"General":5,"Books":6}Page generated in 0.2902 seconds.<br><br><br>", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
parsererror
```

This is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#request_department").change(function(){
        var data = {
            department_id: $(this).val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            {#url: '{{ path("select_options") }} ?category_id' + dep,#}
            url: "{{ url('select_options') }}?dep_id=" + data.department_id,
            data: data,

            success: function(data) {
                window.alert('hi');
                var $option_selector = $('#request_option');

                $option_selector.html('<option>Option</option>');

                for (var i=0, total = data.length; i < total; i++) {
                    $option_selector.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].option + '</option>');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, error){
                console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And this the code in the controller:

```
public function optionAjaxAction(Request $request)
    {

        if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        $id = $request->query->get('dep_id');

        $result = array();

        // Return a list of options, based on the selected department
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyBundle:RequestOption');
        $option = $repo->findByDepartment($id, array('department' => 'asc'));
        //var_dump($hardware);
        foreach ($option as $o) {
            $result[$o->getOption()] = $o->getId();
        }

        return new JsonResponse($result);
    }
```

Im desperate. I would really appreciate any help! Thanks in advance (:

Comment: You need to find out where `Page generated in #.#### seconds.` is being injected into the final response. Maybe you (or a loaded bundle) have set up a [response filter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#after-filters-with-the-kernel-response-event).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are producing `json` and at your client you don't have `dataType` set, so, `dataType='text'` is considered as a intelligent guess.

It would be better if you need to add `dataType:'json',` in your ajax call.

---

As a side not you don't have to send same data twice. You are sending it in the ajax url and in the `data` object too.

Try removing from url:

```
var data = {
    dep_id: $(this).val()
};


 url: "{{ url('select_options') }}",
 data: data,
```

Comment: Already did, did not work. Actually I erased it for this question because I found in another question that that was the problem. :/ Any more suggestions?

Comment: There might be problems with the javascript, but it's certainly not the most immediate problem here. The server response contains extra text, making the json invalid. Before anything, this would need to be fixed.

Comment: ok, adding `dataType='text'` kind of works, now I don't get the error, the problem now is that in the second dropdown I get a list of undefined options. Any ideas? (I get the correct options if i click submit)

Comment: Okay! now you can add `var data = json.parse(data);` as a first line in the success callback and **Don't use a loop** as you have an object not an array.

Comment: @OmarAguinaga Your problem is not in the javascript! Your server response is **invalid** JSON. It contains extra text `"Page generated in 0.2902 seconds.<br><br><br>"`. You should not try to fix that on the client-side.

Comment: @OmarAguinaga agreed with Yoshi. You have to look for this error. That is certainly the issue.

Comment: Thats not extra text generated from nothing, its declared in web/app_dev.php I cannot change that. @jai, but thanks

Comment: @OmarAguinaga If you can't change the fact that something (even if it's manually added in `app_dev.php`) is adding extra content to every response sent by your application, then you'll never be able to return valid json. Are you sure this is a necessity?

Comment: @Yoshi, you are right, didn't solve my problem but it was definitely something i had wrong.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! Now it works, everyone help in a way. A lot of good answer that lead to the solution. Thanks!